# C# ASP.NET insert html code into repeater based on the data from db

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

So needed help again

Sorry a bit confusing but, I am trying to create a chat box which user can submit and then retrieve it again from the DB, I am following this script https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/EkQe7

As you can see, from the HTML code, there is two types, one is when you chat and another is when other people chat,

```
<div class="chat">   
      <div class="chat-history">
        <ul class="chat-ul">
          <li>
            <div class="message-data">
              <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa-circle you"></i> You</span>
            </div>
            <div class="message you-message">
            A new client?!?! I would love to help them, but where are we going to find the time?

            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="clearfix">
            <div class="message-data align-right">
              <span class="message-data-name">Ada, your OperationsAlly</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="message me-message float-right"> We should take a look at your onboarding and service delivery workflows, for most businesess there are many ways to save time and not compromise quality.  </div>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div> <!-- end chat-history -->

    </div> <!-- end chat -->
```

So now, what I am trying to do is from the retrieve the message from DB then code-behind submit the HTML code into the Repeater, 
If it is "You", then will use this code

```
    <div class="message-data">
      <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa-circle you"></i> You</span>
    </div>
    <div class="message you-message">
    A new client?!?! I would love to help them, but where are we going to find the time?

    </div>
```

If it is other people, then will use this code

```
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="message-data align-right">
      <span class="message-data-name">Ada, your OperationsAlly</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="message me-message float-right"> We should take a look at your onboarding and service delivery workflows, for most businesess there are many ways to save time and not compromise quality.  </div>
  </li>
```

My question is how to do that from Code-Behind PageLoad? How to add the code above into the Repeater from code-behind?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap the  `"You"` text in an `<asp:Label>`. Put an `<asp:Literal>` in the repeater where these alternating codes would go. On the `ItemDataBound` event of your `Repeater`, make sure the item type is `Item` or `AlternatingItem`. Get the controls by using `e.Item.FindControl("YourLiteralID")` and `e.Item.FindControl("YourLabelID")`. Populate the literal with your HTML depending on the value of `YourLabelId.Text`.

Comment: Why not use a foreach on the frontend instead of Repeater? `<% foreach (var msg in msgs) { %>
    <div>...<%= msg.txt %>...</div>
  <% } %>`

Comment: @Santi Thanks for the help! But I still cant quite understand, is it possible to provide me the code? sorry!

Comment: @chakeda Hi, How can I do that? sorry I am new to this, first time heard of foreach

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to retrieve the records in the database in the code behind. (See this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx) for details)

```
messages.DataSource = myMessages;
messages.DataBind();
```

Now we can use Repeater, in which the html is separated by author, to iterate the data. Note that I am assuming how your database of messages is structured.

```
<asp:Repeater id="messages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div runat="server" visible='<% (Container.DataItem("author") == "us") %>'>
              <li>
                <div class="message-data">
                  <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa-circle you"></i> You</span>
                </div>
                <div class="message you-message">
                    <%# Eval("testMessage") %>
                </div>
              </li>
        </div>
        <div runat="server" visible='<% (Container.DataItem("author") != "them") %>'>
              <li class="clearfix">
                <div class="message-data align-right">
                  <span class="message-data-name"><%# Eval("authorName") %></span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="message me-message float-right">
                    <%# Eval("testMessage") %>
                </div>
              </li>
        </div>          
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I haven't tested this code, but its a high level idea of what to do. You may also want to see some [Examples on using Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much
Just need some clarification with this part, (Container.DataItem("author") == "us", so this mean that my DB has a attribute which named "author", and if the value inside is "us", then when that repeater is being initiated, that particular code will execute right?

Comment: Correct! As I mentioned, this code is untested - so you may have to work through some errors when you implement this.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot. Learn a lot

Comment: Please upvote/accept if helpful and feel free to comment for extra questions.

Comment: Hi
I received, this error message 
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<% (Container.DataItem("author") == "us") %>' for the 'Visible' property. Do you know what trigger this?